# Can Stack Snippets be added to SO for Teams?

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, stack-overflow-for-teams

SO for Teams is targeted at teams of developers. While that's probably not a classification that applies to *all* its customers, I'd expect the majority of them to be technical teams.

Taking that as given, it seems like a bit of an oversight that Stack Snippets aren't available within a Team - I just went to experiment with something via a Snippet in a team I'm in, and there's no option to add one.

Can snippets be added, pretty please?

Comment: we chose to not include snippets because it has a third party dependency that was not considered to be secure. considering the proprietary nature of private data, we chose to not include it.

Comment: Makes sense, @ChanceHeath. I wonder if it's worth building it in and letting Team admins decide whether to enable it, though? There are teams where the proprietaryness is less of a concern (or not a concern at all), and the gain of snippets would be worth it. The Charcoal team is set up so that it's pretty much public, and is used as a testing ground - for us, snippets would be an awesome thing to have.

Comment: That's a good point. I'll discuss with the team!

Comment: @ChanceHeath just curious what 3rd party component that was?

Comment: @DanielA.White Possibly ajax.googleapis.com.